# CakePhp & PhpUnit 3.5.6 not showing debug output

Tags: cakephp, phpunit

On my cakephp 2 project I needed to upgrade my phpunit framework to 3.6.12. After this change,  when running unit tests the debug output is not shown in the test results anymore.

Searching the web indicates that since phpunit 3.6 a parameter --debug is required to capture the debug ouput..

Is there a away to re-enable the debug output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior was changed [ten months ago](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/411#issuecomment-2773436) so that debug output shows by default without the `--debug` flag. This works for me with 3.6.12.

**Test Case**

```
class OutputTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    function testOutput() {
        echo 'foo';
    }
}
```

**Running**

```
phpunit OutputTest.php
```

**Output**

```
PHPUnit 3.6.12 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.foo

Time: 1 second, Memory: 5.00Mb

OK (1 test, 0 assertions)
```